# What does --i do in a square root function?

Tags: c, function, loops, for-loop

In a square root function (in C) like this one:

```
double squareRoot(double n) {
   double i, precision = 0.00001;

   for(i = 1; i*i <=n; ++i);   //Integer part

   for(--i; i*i < n; i += precision);  //Fractional part

   return i;
}
```

what does this **--i** part(on line 4) do?

It works fine and for input 24, it gives 4.898980. But when this **--i** is replaced with just **i**, the result is 5.000000. Also, when **i--** is used, it gives 4.898980 again. So, does that mean **--i = i--**? What's happening under the hood?

Also, I don't get the logic why just an **i** wouldn't suffice here as we're already done with the integer part. I'm a novice. Help please?

Comment: The meaning of `--i` and `i--` can be found in any basic text book or using a search on the web.

Comment: After a sequence point (which is the `;` right after the `--i`) the `i` will have the same value for both `i--` and `--i`.

Comment: It does the same thing in that function as it would do anywhere else. It's a pre-decrement operation.

Comment: Because after the first loop `i` was `1` out of range. So the second loop decrements it, to be in range so it can step through in much smaller increments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a 'step back', e.g. if you're doing `sqrt(50)` (7.07....)

```
for(i = 1; i*i <=n; ++i);   //Integer part
```

then `i` will finish at 8. But that's obviously PAST where the sqrt value actually is. so

```
for(--i; i*i < n; i += precision);  //Fractional part
```

will move back one step, and effectively run as

```
for(i=7; i*i < n; i += precision);  //Fractional part
```

and slowly work its way up to as close to 7.07.... as the precision will allow.

Comment: Clear now. Thanks!